# converting id3 version with python

Tags: python, id3

I've been searching for hours and have found nothing. I already have a way of returning the ID3 version but I then want to convert it ID3v2.2 if its not already. iTunes can do this (right click, convert ID3) but its a bulky solution and I want this feature streamlined into my python script.

python

```
from tagger import *
audio = ID3v2('example.mp3')      
id3_version = audio.version
if id3_version != '2.2':
  #convert it to 2.2
```

Comment: There is no library called "tagger" with a class called "ID3v2" in the standard library, so you'll have to tell us which one you're using. Also, are you trying to convert v2.3 and 2.4 to 2.2, or convert v1 to 2.2?

Comment: I am using pytagger. I want to convert any version that isnt 2.2 to 2.2

Comment: The fact that it's possible in iTunes doesn't mean that every ID3v2 library in the world has a way to do it. This particular library is undocumented, only has a single developer, and hasn't been updated since version 0.5 in 2006, so the only way you're likely to find out is to read the code yourself, or to ask the developer. And there's a good chance it isn't possible. If you're willing to switch libraries, there are other options where it definitely is possible to do this, and documented how to do so.